# Unable to fix Error 10038 WSAENOTSOCK

Tags: sockets

I'm trying to learn Berkeley Socket programming, but I am really stuck here:
I have a 10038 error both of my server and client program, according to the MSDN it means: "*An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket*" but my socket is a "socket".  Here is the server/client code:

my client :

```
#include <winsock.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 32

void DieWithError(char *errorMessage);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int sock, bytesLen;
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
    unsigned short servPort =13;
    char * servIP;
    char buff[BUFFSIZE+1];
    WSADATA wsaData;

    if(argc == 2){
        servIP = argv[1];
    }

    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsaData) != 0){
        puts("ERROR WSA");
    }

    if(sock=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) < 0){
        puts("ERROR socket");
    }

    memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
    servAddr.sin_family   = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_port     = htons(servPort);
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(&servIP);

    if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)<0)){
        DieWithError("connect Error");
    }

    while(bytesLen=read(sock, buff, BUFFSIZE)){
        buff[bytesLen]= '\n';
    }

    printf("Heure : %s",buff);

    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}

void DieWithError(char *errorMessage)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"%s: %d\n",
    errorMessage, WSAGetLastError());
    exit(1);
}
```

and my sever:

```
#include <winsock.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define MAXLINE 32

void DieWithError(char *errorMessage);

int main(){

    int sock, sockc;
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
    unsigned short servPort =13;
    time_t ticks;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    char buff[MAXLINE];
    char * servIP;

    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsaData) != 0){
        puts("ERROR WSA");
    }

    if(sock=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) < 0){
        puts("ERROR socket");
    }
    servIP = "10.1.1.3";
    memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
    servAddr.sin_family   = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_port     = htons(servPort);
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if(bind(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr) < 0)){
        DieWithError("bind)()");
    }

    if(listen(sock,MAXQUEUE) < 0){
        DieWithError("listen ()");
    }

    while(1){

        sockc = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)NULL, NULL);
        ticks = time(NULL);
        snprintf(buff,sizeof(buff),"%s",ctime(&ticks));

        write(buff, sizeof(buff), MAXLINE);
    }

    return 0;
}

void DieWithError(char *errorMessage)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"%s: %d\n",
        errorMessage, WSAGetLastError());
    exit(1);
}
```

each start i have a 10038 on the `connect()` function of the client and a 10038 on the `bind()` function on the server.

THANKS for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike other platforms, Windows does not use file descriptors to represent sockets.  It uses actual kernel objects.  Other platforms use `int` to represent open file descriptors, and thus to represent sockets.  Windows uses the `SOCKET` type instead, which is a typedef for `UINT_PTR` (`unsigned int` in 32bit, `unsigned __int64` in 64bit) so it can accommodate object handles.  The `socket()` function on Windows returns `INVALID_SOCKET` (which is `(SOCKET)(~0)`) on error, while other platforms return `(int)-1` instead.  You need to make sure you account for this so you do not slice/truncate legitimate socket handles on Windows.

When your client is calling `inet_addr()`, it is passing a `char**` where a `char*` is expected.  Your compiler should have reported an error on that.

As sockets are not represented as file descriptors on Windows, you cannot use the `read()` and `write()` functions with Windows sockets. You must use the `recv()`/`WSARecv()` and `send()`/`WSASend()` functions instead.  And you need to handle the case where the functions can return `SOCKET_ERROR` (-1) on error.

Try something more like this instead:

client :

```
#include <winsock.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 32

void DieWithErrorCode(char *errorMessage, int errCode);
void DieWithError(char *errorMessage, int *errCode = NULL);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SOCKET sock;
    int ret;
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
    unsigned short servPort = 13;
    char *servIP;
    char buff[BUFFSIZE];
    WSADATA wsaData;

    if (argc != 2) {
        DieWithErrorCode("ERROR argc", WSAEINVAL);
    }
    servIP = argv[1];

    ret = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsaData);
    if (ret != 0) {
        DieWithErrorCode("ERROR WSAStartup", ret);
    }

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        DieWithError("ERROR socket");
    }

    memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(servPort);
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(servIP);
    if (servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr == INET_NONE) {
        DieWithErrorCode("ERROR inet_addr", WSAEINVAL);
    }

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        DieWithError("ERROR connect");
    }

    while(1) {
        ret = recv(sock, buff, BUFFSIZE, 0);
        if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            DieWithError("ERROR recv");
        }

        if (ret == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "disconnected\n");
            break;
        }

        printf("Heure : %.*s\n", ret, buff);
    }

    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}

void DieWithErrorCode(char *errorMessage, int errCode)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %d\n", errorMessage, errCode);
    exit(1);
}

void DieWithError(char *errorMessage)
{
    DieWithErrorCode(errorMessage, WSAGetLastError());
}
```

server:

```
#include <winsock.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXLINE 32

void DieWithErrorCode(char *errorMessage, int errCode);
void DieWithError(char *errorMessage);

int main()
{
    SOCKET sock, sockc;
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
    unsigned short servPort = 13;
    time_t ticks;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    char buff[MAXLINE];
    int ret, buflen;

    ret = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsaData);
    if (ret != 0) {
        DieWithErrorCode("ERROR WSA", ret);
    }

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        DieWithError("ERROR socket");
    }

    memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(servPort);
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        DieWithError("ERROR bind");
    }

    if (listen(sock, MAXQUEUE) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        DieWithError("ERROR listen");
    }

    while(1) {
        sockc = accept(sock, NULL, NULL);
        if (sockc == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            DieWithError("ERROR accept");
        }

        ticks = time(NULL);
        buflen = snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%s", ctime(&ticks));
        if (send(sockc, buff, buflen, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR send: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        }

        closesocket(sockc);
    }

    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}

void DieWithErrorCode(char *errorMessage, int errCode)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"%s: %d\n", errorMessage, errCode);
    exit(1);
}

void DieWithError(char *errorMessage)
{
    DieWithErrorCode(char *errorMessage, WSAGetLastError());
}
```